# How can I add section names in the Attributes inspector in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, inspector, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

Is there any way to add section name in newly added `@IBDesignable` properties for better readability.

```
//
//MARK: - Badge
//
@IBInspectable
var badgeColor:UIColor = UIColor.darkGray {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var showBadgeOnIndex:Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        if showBadgeOnIndex >= buttons.count {
            showBadgeOnIndex = 0
        }
        updateView()
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var showAllBadge:Bool = false {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var hideAllBadge:Bool = true {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}
```

ex:

[image: Example attributes in the Attributes inspector]

In the picture above, the view properties have the section name **View**.

Any help would be appreciated.

I already know that the name of the custom class will appear as the section name in the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: You can create a subclass for it that could make it work. Each subclass will have its section name with its properties designable.

Comment: @Larme Okay but creating so many subclasses for small set of operation not so good approach. thanks by the way for the solution.

Comment: Indeed, that's not a good idea, just to have a "opinion based better looking window in Interface Builder". But since the section title take the name of the class, it have to be a subclass to get it work as you want. If you were having multiple composants (with a sense at each step of the "inheritance family tree), then it could be ok to do so.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sections and their titles in the Attributes inspector are generated based on what exact classes the properties in that section belong to. There is **no way** to change this behavior.

However, Xcode automatically groups the inspectable properties that have similar names. Those groups are separated with a line. This behavior is also visible in your example picture:

[image: separator between automatically created groups]

Comment: Okay, Thanks but it's great if we will able to provide subsections in the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

By default your `classname` (A name of your custom class) becomes a title for IBDesignable properties

Here is reference documents, what you want. [IBInspectable / IBDesignable](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/)

[image]

Comment: The OP states in the question that they are already aware of that information.

Comment: @the4kman Oh, you are right, I did not read that... let me check any other feasible solution